# Read Cookies using Javascript

Tags: javascript, cookies

I want to create a cookie using php,an also i need to read it using javascript.ie,
by using setcookie('mycookie','hello',time()+34000) in php i am creating a cookie in my system.Now,i need to read it using javascript.Is it possible?If anybody knows please give me some idea.Please....help me.I am using javscript as follows

```
<script language="javascript">

    function Get_Cookie( check_name ) {
    // first we'll split this cookie up into name/value pairs
    // note: document.cookie only returns name=value, not the other components
    var a_all_cookies = document.cookie.split( ';' );
    var a_temp_cookie = '';
    var cookie_name = '';
    var cookie_value = '';
    var b_cookie_found = false; // set boolean t/f default f

    for ( i = 0; i < a_all_cookies.length; i++ )
    {
        // now we'll split apart each name=value pair
        a_temp_cookie = a_all_cookies[i].split( '=' );


        // and trim left/right whitespace while we're at it
        cookie_name = a_temp_cookie[0].replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');

        // if the extracted name matches passed check_name
        if ( cookie_name == check_name )
        {
            b_cookie_found = true;
            // we need to handle case where cookie has no value but exists (no = sign, that is):
            if ( a_temp_cookie.length > 1 )
            {
                cookie_value = unescape( a_temp_cookie[1].replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '') );
            }
            // note that in cases where cookie is initialized but no value, null is returned
            return cookie_value;
            break;
        }
        a_temp_cookie = null;
        cookie_name = '';
    }
    if ( !b_cookie_found )
    {
        return null;
    }
}
 if (Get_Cookie('__gsb'))
   {
alert('Found');
}
</script>`
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Shortest function for reading a cookie in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5639346/shortest-function-for-reading-a-cookie-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here's a nice post](http://www.satya-weblog.com/2007/05/php-and-javascript-cookie.html) that demonstrates this scenario. In order to make a cookie accessible through scripting languages such as javascript it must have the `HttpOnly` property set to `false`. This is the last parameter of the [setcookie](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) function.

Comment: Thank you for your help to move forward..Sorry for late aknoledgement.Thanks again