# Cloudfront Lambda@edge set cookie on Viewer Request

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront, aws-lambda-edge

**Update: Collected my thoughts better**

I'm generating a unique identifier (UUID) for each user in the Viewer Request Lambda, and then selecting a cached page to return based upon that UUID. This works.

Ideally, this user would always have the same UUID.

**I must generate that UUID in the Viewer Request** if it is not present in a cookie on that Viewer Request. I also need that UUID to be set as a cookie, which of course happens in the response not the request.

Without caching, my server simply handles taking a custom header and creating a Set-Cookie in the response header.

I am not finding a way to handle this if I want to cache the page. I can ignore the request header for caching and serve the correct cached page, but then the user does not persist that UUID as no cookie is set to be utilized in their next request.

Has anyone accomplished something like this?

**Things I'm trying**

There are a few angles I'm working on with this, but haven't been able to get to work yet:

1. Some sort of setting in Cloudfront I'm unaware of that handles the header or other data pass-through from Viewer Request to Viewer Response, which could be used in a second lambda in Cloudfront.
2. Modify the response object headers preemptively in the Viewer Request. I don't think this is possible, as they return headers are not yet created, unless there's some built-in Cloudfront methodology I'm missing.
3. An existing pass-through header of some sort, I don't know if that's even a thing since I'm not intimately familiar with this aspect of request-response handling, but worth a shot.
4. Possibly (haven't tried yet though) I could create the entire response object in the Client Request lambda and somehow serve the cached page from there, modifying the response headers then passing it into the callback method.

[Tobin's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55128779?noredirect=1) answer actually works, but is not a solid solution. If the user is not storing or serving their cookies it becomes an infinite loop, plus I'd rather not throw a redirect up in front of all of my pages if I can avoid it

---

**Somewhat-working concept**

1. Viewer Request Lambda, when UUID not present in cookies, generates UUID
2. Viewer Request Lambda sets UUID in cookies on header in request object. Callback with updated request object passed in
3. Presence of UUID cookie busts Cloudfront cache
4. Origin Request Lambda is triggered with UUID present
5. Origin Request Lambda calls original request URL again via `http.get` with UUID cookie set (40KB limit makes doing this in the Viewer Request Lambda impractical)
6. Second scenario for Viewer Request Lambda, seeing UUID now present, strips the UUID cookie then continues the request normally
7. Second Origin Request if not yet cached - Cached response if cached, as cache-busting UUID is not present - returns actual page HTML to First Origin Request
8. First Origin Request receives response from `http.get` containing HTML
9. First Origin Request creates custom response object containing response body from `http.get` and Set-Cookie header set with our original UUID

Subsequent calls, having the UUID already set, will strip the UUID from the cookie (to prevent cache busting) and skip directly to the second-scenario in the Viewer Request Lambda which will directly load the cached version of the page.

I say "somewhat" because when I try to hit my endpoint, I get a binary file downloaded.

**EDIT**

This is because I was not setting the `content-type` header. I now have only a 302 redirect problem... if I overcome this I'll post a full answer.

---

**Original question**

I have a function on the Viewer Request that picks an option and sets some things in the request before it's retrieved from the cache or server.

That works, but I want it to remember that choice for future users. The thought is to simply set a cookie I can read the next time that user comes through. As this is on the Viewer Request and not the Viewer Response I haven't figured out how to make that happen, or if it even is possible via the Lambda itself.

```
Viewer Request -> 
  Lambda picks options (needs to set cookie) -> 
    gets corresponding content -> 
      returns to Viewer with set-cookie header intact
```

I have [seen the examples](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-examples.html) and been able to set cookies successfully in the Viewer Response via a Lambda. That doesn't help me much as the decision needs to be made on the request. Quite unsurprisingly adding this code into the Viewer Request shows nothing in the response.

Comment: I was going to leave a comment, but it was too long and had to leave an answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would argue that the really correct way to set a nonexistent cookie would be to return a 302 redirect to the same URI with `Set-Cookie`, and let the browser redo the request.  This probably would not have much of an impact since the browser can reuse the same connection to "follow" the redirect.

But if you insist on not doing it that way, then you can inject the cookie into the request with your Viewer Request trigger and then emit a `Set-Cookie` with the same value in your Viewer Response trigger.

The *request* object, in a viewer *response* event, can be found at the same place where it's found in the original *request* event, `event.Records[0].cf.request`.

In a viewer-response trigger, this part of the structure contains the [*"request that CloudFront received from the viewer and that might have been modified by the Lambda function that was triggered by a viewer request event."*](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-event-structure.html#lambda-event-structure-response)

Use caution to ensure that you handle the cookie header correctly.  The [`Cookie` request header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cookie) requires careful and accurate manipulation because the browser [can use multiple formats](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49409403/1695906) when multiple cookies exist.

Once upon a time, cookies were required to be sent as a single request header.

```
Cookie: foo=bar; buzz=fizz
```

Parse these by splitting the values on `;` followed by `<space>`.

But the browser may also split them with multiple headers, like this:

```
Cookie: foo=bar
Cookie: buzz=fizz
```

In the latter case, the array `event.Records[0].cf.request.headers.cookie` will contain multiple members.  You need to examine the `value` attribute of each object in that array, check for multiple values within each, as well as accommodating the fact that the array will be completely undefined (not empty) if no cookies exist.

---

Bonus: Here's a function I wrote, that I believe correctly handles all cases including the case where there are no cookies.  It will extract the cookie with the name you are looking for.  [Cookie names are case-sensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11312272/1695906).

```js
// extract a cookie value from request headers, by cookie name
// const my_cookie_value = extract_cookie(event.Records[0].cf.request.headers,'MYCOOKIENAME');
// returns null if the cookie can't be found
// https://stackoverflow.com/a/55436033/1695906

function extract_cookie(headers, cname) {

    const cookies = headers['cookie'];
    if(!cookies)
    {
        console.log("extract_cookie(): no 'Cookie:' headers in request");
        return null;
    }

    // iterate through each Cookie header in the request, last to first

    for (var n = cookies.length; n--;)
    {
        // examine all values within each header value, last to first

        const cval = cookies[n].value.split(/;\ /);
        const vlen = cval.length;

        for (var m = vlen; m--;)
        {
            const cookie_kv = cval[m].split('=');
            if(cookie_kv[0] === cname)
            {
                return cookie_kv[1];
            }            
        } // for m (each value)    
    } // for n (each header)

    // we have no match if we reach this point
    console.log('extract_cookie(): cookies were found, but the specified cookie is absent');
    return null;

}
```

Comment: @RandyHall I edited this answer after it was accepted, to add a `Cookie:` header parsing function.

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to add another directory: with the first cookie setter request, return (from the lambda) a redirect which includes the cookie-set header, that redirects to your actual content?

OK, long way round but:

- Take cookie instruction from the incoming request
- Set this somewhere (cache, etc)
- Let the request get your object
- on the Response, also call a function that reads the (cache) and sets the set-cookie header on the response if needed?

Comment: That's an interesting theory. It sounds like a possibility but the redirect would not be ideal.

Answer (score 0):

It's been more than one year since the question was published. I hope you found a solution and you can share it with us!

I am facing the same problem and I've thinking also about the infinite loop... What about this?

- The viewer request event sends back a 302 response with the cookie set, e.g. `uuid=whatever` **and a GET parameter** added to the URL in the Location header, e.g. `_uuid_set_=1`.
- In the next viewer request where the GET parameter `_uuid_set_` is set (and equals 1, but this is not needed), there will be two options:

  - Either the cookie `uuid` is not set, in which case you can send back a response 500 to break the loop, or whatever fits your needs,
  - or the cookie is set, in which case you send another 302 back with the parameter `_uuid_set_` removed, so that it is never seen by the end user and cannot be copy-pasted and shared and we all can sleep at night.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for how to do this using [CloudFront Functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/cloudfront-functions.html) instead of Lambda@Edge (similar to *Michael - sqlbot*'s approach above):

**Viewer Request**

```js
var crypto = require("crypto");

function generateUID(requestId) {
  var hash = crypto
    .createHash('sha256')
    .update(requestId + String(Math.random()))
    .digest('hex');
  return hash;
}

function handler(event) {
  var request = event.request;
  if (!request.cookies['test_uid']) {
    request.headers['x-test-uid'] = {
      value: generateUID(event.context.requestId)
    };
  }
  return request;
}
```

**Viewer Response**

```js
function handler(event) {
  var request = event.request;
  var response = event.response;

  if ('x-test-uid' in request.headers) {
    var uid = request.headers['x-test-uid'].value;
    response.cookies["test_uid"] = { value: uid };
  }

  return response;
}
```