# how to keep radio button checked after page refresh?

Tags: php, javascript, radio-button, refresh, checked

i have many radio buttons inside foreach loop and it's onclick it goes to it's corresponding url  . i want the selected radio button stays checked after page refresh using php or javascript. sorry for my broken english.

```
<ul>
 <?php foreach($companyStatus as $statuses => $status): ?>
  <li>

   <input
   type="radio"
   value="<?php echo $url?>"
   name="group1"
   onclick="if(this.checked){window.location=this.value;}"
   ><?php echo htmlspecialchars($status['fldStatusName'])?>

 </li>
<?php endforeach;?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Do you mean after REFRESH or after POSTING the form?

Comment: there is no form just url .after getting data from database

Comment: Meaning what? I think you need to describe this a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

Set a cookie with Javascript (onclick of the radio button) and include a script like this:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() { READ COOKIE FUNCTION HERE }, false);
```

See [Get cookie by name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10730362/javascript-get-cookie-by-name) on how to read a specific cookie. Then, set the radio button according with the state in the cookie.

//edit: some more details

1. Bind an event listener to your radio button which sets a cookie `document.getElementById('radiobuttonid').addEventListener('click', function() { SET COOKIE HERE }, false);` (see http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp for how to set a cookie)
2. add the above mentioned listener to your html page `window.addEventListener('load', function() { READ COOKIE FUNCTION HERE }, false);`

The READ COOKIE FUNCTION HERE includes reading the cookie value for the radio button and setting the attribute **checked="checked"** for it.

To get even more info, you may refer to http://www.somacon.com/p143.php (also some sorcecode, but I didn't check it).

Comment: Thanx Martin but it's  totally new for me can you plz expalin it a bit more .

Comment: I hope it's more clear now. The page mentioned in the bottom has some code ready, too (for reading and setting radio button values).

Answer (score 0):

You need to record the radio buttons' selected checked state either in a cookie or as a session variable or in a flatfile or db.  Which method is the best is up to you, depends on how long you want your script to "remember" it, how many radio buttons there are to "remember", how "well" you want it to be remembered (eg: using a cookie only would not be the best way for long term because clients can easily delete it)