# How change HTML document after false onsubmit without manual page reloading

Tags: javascript, forms, onsubmit

I want to change HTML document elements when the onsubmit event handler returns false.

Inside function `validate()` a cookie is set (BTW, is there simpler way than cookie?).

Onload event handler `checkIfFalseSubmit()` checks cookie and runs function `changeDocument()` that changes document.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>How change document after false onsubmit without manual page reloading</title> 
<script type="text/javascript">
function validate() {
  // http://www.javascripter.net/faq/settinga.htm
  var today = new Date();
  var expire = new Date();
  expire.setTime(today.getTime() + 1000*5000);
  document.cookie = "cookie1=a; expires=" + expire.toGMTString();
  alert ("Always false - just for testing");
  return false;
}

function changeDocument() {
  myDiv.innerHTML = "Form validation failed"; 
} 

// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10730362/javascript-get-cookie-by-name
function getCookie(name) {
  var parts = document.cookie.split(name + "=");
  if (parts.length == 2) return parts.pop().split(";").shift();
}

function checkIfFalseSubmit() {
  if ( getCookie("cookie1") == "a")
    changeDocument();
}
</script> 
</head>

<body onload="checkIfFalseSubmit()">
<div id="myDiv">Before Submit</div>

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>" method="post" name="f" onsubmit="return validate();" > 
 <input type="text" name="myName" /><br/>
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Problem is that `onload` happens only when I manually reload page. 
Without reloading the alert is shown but the document remains unchanged.

Is there another event that I should use instead of onload for my purpose? 
Is there another way to get my goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is overly convoluted. You don't have to use cookies and and body onload event. Just keep `validate()` called on form submit  and `changeDocument()` to display your message.

Inside of `validate()` if validation failed call `changeDocument()` before returning false.

Comment: **It works**. Your response answers _exactly_ the question I stated. No complains. But for more complicated example (more events, more document changes), what's the best way to remember page state client-side?

Comment: You don't need to remember client state for validation - if validation fail, form simple won't be submitted. If you need this for a different scenario - please specify which one.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Now, I have no different scenario. I see, my true problem is understanding browser behavior when onsubmit handler returns its value. I've been expecting some _special_ event.