# Keep user selected background throughout all the pages on the site

Tags: javascript, html, css, cookies, background-image

I made a background picker for a page. There are 4 different background-images that users can select from.

Here is my code and script I used for this:

HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li id="color-1"></li>
  <li id="color-2"></li>
  <li id="color-3"></li>
  <li id="color-4"></li>
</ul>
```

SCRIPT:

```
<script>
    $('ul li').click(function() {
    var background = $(this).css('background-image');
    $("html, body").css("background-image", background);
});
</script>
```

The issue is that when I switch page the background image resets to the default one.
I know this could be  handled by setting cookies. I tried several methods, but none worked.

Can someone please help me out with this one?

Comment: Have you actually tried using cookies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When selected, store the background in the localStorage

```
<script>
    $('ul li').click(function() {
    var background = $(this).css('background-image');
    $("html, body").css("background-image", background);
    localStorage.background = background;
});
</script>
```

When loading a page, apply it.

```
$("html, body").css("background-image", localStorage.background);
```

Comment: I ended up using this code snippet. It works in all the main and sub-pages.

Also works in all browsers I tested.
Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Save the background variable in a cookie:

```
document.cookie = "bgimage=" + background;
```

then get the cookie:

```
$(function(){
   var bgCookie = getCookie("bgimage");
   $("html, body").css("background-image", bgCookie);
});

function getCookie(name) {
  var parts = document.cookie.split(name + "=");
  if (parts.length == 2) return parts.pop().split(";").shift();
}
```

`getCookie()` method taken from: [Get cookie by name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10730362/javascript-get-cookie-by-name)

Comment: This worked with the main pages, but when I added sub-pages (in sub-folders) it got screwed up.
Also did not work in Opera at all.
But thank you for the post.

Answer (score 0):

you can add custom-background.js plugin to your website

https://github.com/CybrSys/custom-background.js