# Javascript get php variable from other website

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to make an HTML5 and PHP based web application.The objective of the application would be to fetch the data from another PHP based website and use that  data within my application.How do I do it?

Comment: This question is very broad. Please go do some more research and familiarize yourself with the basics of the techniques used. One of your keywords is `JSONP`.

Answer (score 1):

The above answer is partially incorrect; PHP doesn't have access to localStorage. However, you can use cookies to achieve what you want - although you CAN use JSON with AJAX, but I think cookies are easier. Since you're very new to JavaScript, I'll show you an example.

Let's assume I'm making a very insecure login system. Let's say:

```
$name = "John"; //set the name to John.
```

Now, to let JavaScript access this name variable, we'd have to use cookies. You can use them like so:

```
$username = "John"; //set the name to John.
setcookie("username", $username, time()+86400);
```

The setcookie method take the paramaters:

```
setcookie(name, value, expire, path, domain);
```

So in our case, it sets the name to username, the value to the user's name, the expiry date from 1 hour from now (60*60*24). This cookie will expire in one day.

Now, once this is done, make sure this function is added in your scripts.

```
function getCookie(name) {
  var value = "; " + document.cookie;
  var parts = value.split("; " + name + "=");
  if (parts.length == 2) return parts.pop().split(";").shift();
}
```

Please credit the original author at [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10730362/get-cookie-by-name) for the code above.

Then, to get the cookie, simply do:

```
name = getCookie(username);
```

I hope I helped!

Comment: Ok, I understand all of the php. However I do not understand where I am supposed to put the url location of the php file. Sorry I must seem  rather stupid asking this question.

Comment: Just a wording issue: note that the other answer may appear above or below your answer, depending on their relative score.

Comment: @checked01, if you want it to be asynchronous, you'll have to use AJAX. I'm not that familiar with it, so you'll have to Google it :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use "cookies" or "localStorage"

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Comment: There are other sources better than W3Schools. Why? [w3fools](http://w3fools.com)

Comment: have these too and anything you put on google and search. http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html and http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2009/06/html5_storage_t.html