# How to send ajax post request for a video file in Django?

Tags: javascript, html, django, ajax, django-models

I would like to send an AJAX POST request to a Django view in order to handle a video file. I am developing a basic webpage where users can record video and audio using their camera. Once the user stops recording, the recorded video file will be automatically sent to a backend view where it will be saved to the database. Below is my current JavaScript code.

```
<script>
    var csrftoken = '{{ csrf_token }}';
</script>
<script>
window.onload = function () {
    const parts = [];
    let mediaRecorder;
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true, video: true}).then(stream => {
        document.getElementById("video").srcObject = stream;
        document.getElementById("btn").onclick = function () {
            mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);

            mediaRecorder.start(1000);

            mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function(e) {
                parts.push(e.data);
            }
        }
    });


    document.getElementById("stopbtn").onclick = function () {
        mediaRecorder.stop();
        const blob = new Blob(parts, {
            type: "video/webm"
        });

        // Create a FormData object to send the Blob
        let formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("video_blob", blob, "filename.webm");

        // Make the ajax call
        $.ajax({
            url: '/recorder/',
            type: 'POST',   
            success: function (res) {
                console.log("video uploaded successfully")
            },      
            data: formData,
            headers: {
                'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken,
            },                
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false
        });
    }
};
```

This is the view I want to send it to where I will eventually save it to the database.

```
def save_video(request):
    if request.method == "POST" and request.FILES.get("video_blob"):
        uploaded_blob = request.FILES["video_blob"]
        Models.objects.create(video_file = uploaded_blob ) # wish to do something like this

        return JsonResponse({"message": "Video uploaded successfully."})

    return render(request, 'recorder/index.html')
```

Please include csrf tokens for your answers, because I don't know how to add the missing csrf token for my post request in this situation. Also, please take security into consideration if there are any.

Thank you, and please leave any comments below if you have questions.

Comment: does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23350040

Comment: you can also check the documentation; https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/csrf/

Comment: no it wasn't what I was asking in the question.

Comment: You are asking include csrf token since you dont know how. The links I provided shows how to add. Are you sure it is not what you are looking for?

Comment: I don't know how I can send a video file through ajax post request to the django view. The csrf token is just one of the errors that I am getting while trying to do this.

Comment: Then first add the csrf token to fix the csrf error. Next check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10899796 (ignore the php part)

Comment: I would like to add a csrf token, but I don't have a form because I don't need one. I updated my question, please take a look.

Comment: Yes. **add** the csrf to your ajax. I can see you are using ajax but it is still required to use csrf when running a **post** request (unless you use `csrf_exempt` )

Comment: On the first link that I sent, scroll down to check the ajax part of csrf token !

Comment: I added the script tag `<script>
    var csrftoken = '{{ csrf_token }}';
</script>` with the csrf token, but I don't know how I should embed this in my ajax request. Would you mind posting an answer on how I can do this? Code for the full javascript would be appreciated/

Comment: Did you check the other answers on my first link? Or did you only check the answer that I added. Did you check the documentation I also sent?

Comment: Like I said, add the csrftoken on the ajax. If you did and still not working, update the question. How to add the csrftoken on the ajax is also on the same page on the first link that I added. I also added a url link on how to submit an ajax request that includes a file.

Comment: checking on your answer, I guess you already added the part to include the file (blob) in ajax. Fix the csrf token first.

Comment: I added the csrf token and updated my answer to show my most recent code. Is it correct?

Comment: Did you confirm the value of csrftoken? is it null or not? Can you send the post request? You can also add csrftoken via header if `{{ csrf_token }}` 's value is null

Comment: Did you test it after adding? Were there any error message after?

Comment: In one of the answers, this should be correct.