# Javascript login time clock

Tags: javascript, html, dom

i want to make a javascript clock which will start when ever a user login and will run until user logout

currentlty i am doing it with `setInterval` and calling it after every second and add 1 second into previous time . Is there any better solution ?

**Note :** Clock should also work even if user refresh browser

Comment: if rigid to js , then you have to use localstorage ,but i suggest better to use server side scripting ..

Answer (score 2):

I would echo Rohit's Comment but for an alternative JS soloution I would use javascripts Date object.
Something like the below:

```
var logInTime = new Date();

var logoutTime = new Date();

var loggedInLength = logoutTime.getTime() - logInTime.getTime();
var seconds = loggedInLength / 1000
var minutes = seconds / 60
var hours = minutes / 60
```

Just set the logInTime on login and the logoutTime on logout

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wayahrm4/)

Edit: I missed your note about clock working through refresh, to implement this without using serverside code you could use either local storage as suggested or set a cookie.

```
document.cookie = 'logintime='+logInTime.getTime()
```

look at this SO answer on how to retrieve a cookie by name: [Get Cookie By Name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26234977/2304693)