# How to redirect visitor using js

Tags: javascript, html, redirect

How to redirect User in No.1 html page to another No. 2 html page using javascript when a user visit first time in No.1 page. If possible pls help me.

Comment: Depends if first time means first time ever or first time this session. If it's the later you should use a session, otherwise a cookie should do the job. You have shown nearly no effort in asking this question. What have you tried? Code please.

Answer (score 1):

Just use cookie to mark the user first time and redirect it with `document.location`:

```
if ( getCookie( 'first-time' ) === undefined ) {
    setCookie( 'first-time', 'yes' );
    document.location = '/second-page-url';
}
```

To use cookie read this [Set cookie and get cookie with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14573223/set-cookie-and-get-cookie-with-javascript) and this [Get cookie by name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10730362/get-cookie-by-name)

Comment: you can also use localstorage

Comment: Or local storage, true

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a cookie on the first visit, then you can check the user was there before on your site.

Answer (score 0):

To check 1st visit or not one can use cookie or localStorage. 
And to redirect there are several methods/mechanisms: [this article explains it well](https://css-tricks.com/redirect-web-page/)

Answer (score 0):

Agree with **legotin**, but you will need to read/write cookie somehow:

**Read cookie:**

```
function getCookie(name) {
      var matches = document.cookie.match(new RegExp(
        "(?:^|; )" + name.replace(/([\.$?*|{}\(\)\[\]\\\/\+^])/g, '\\$1') + "=([^;]*)"));
      return matches ? decodeURIComponent(matches[1]) : undefined;
    }
```

**Set cookie:**

```
function setCookie(name, value, options) {
  options = options || {};

  var expires = options.expires;

  if (typeof expires == "number" && expires) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + expires * 1000);
    expires = options.expires = d;
  }
  if (expires && expires.toUTCString) {
    options.expires = expires.toUTCString();
  }

  value = encodeURIComponent(value);

  var updatedCookie = name + "=" + value;

  for (var propName in options) {
    updatedCookie += "; " + propName;
    var propValue = options[propName];
    if (propValue !== true) {
      updatedCookie += "=" + propValue;
    }
  }

  document.cookie = updatedCookie;
}
```