# Countdown timer for hours, minutes, and seconds

Tags: javascript, cookies, timer

How to set cookie for this count down timer?
The cookie should prevent resetting timer while I am refreshing the page.

```
<div id="hms">02:00:00</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function count() {
        var startTime = document.getElementById('hms').innerHTML;
        var pieces = startTime.split(':');
        var time = new Date();
        time.setHours(pieces[0]);
        time.setMinutes(pieces[1]);
        time.setSeconds(pieces[2]);
        var timedif = new Date(time.valueOf() - 1000);
        var newtime = timedif.toTimeString().split(' ')[0];
        document.getElementById('hms').innerHTML = newtime;
        setTimeout(count,1000);
    }
    count();
</script>
```

Comment: How about code instead of image ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<strike>The problem is if you save the time in cookie just before refresh and retrieve it after page loads it may not match the real current time because page may take arbitrary amount of time to refresh, 1st time it may be 1 sec 2nd time may be faster and take 0.5 sec due to factors like caching etc. for users on slower network it may be always more than 1-2 seconds. So the time on the page will always lag and won't match the real current time after a few refreshes.</strike>

Looks like i was wrong browser don't refresh the content already on the page until all required resources are downloaded so your counter keeps going as well as setting cookies until its all ready

Here is what i got to work

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="hms">02:00:00</div>
</body>

<script>
var startTime;
function getCookie(name) {
  var value = "; " + document.cookie;
  var parts = value.split("; " + name + "=");
  if (parts.length == 2) return parts.pop().split(";").shift();
} // credits kirlich @http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10730362/get-cookie-by-name

function count() {
 if(typeof getCookie('remaining')!= 'undefined')
 {
   startTime = getCookie('remaining');
 }
 else if(document.getElementById('hms').innerHTML.trim()!='')
 {
   startTime = document.getElementById('hms').innerHTML;
 }
 else
 {
  var d = new Date(); 
  var h=d.getHours(); 
  var m=d.getMinutes();
  var s=d.getSeconds();
  startTime = h+':'+m+':'+s;
  //OR
  startTime  = d.toTimeString().split(" ")[0]
 }

 var pieces = startTime.split(":");
 var time = new Date();
 time.setHours(pieces[0]);
 time.setMinutes(pieces[1]);
 time.setSeconds(pieces[2]);
 var timediff = new Date(time.valueOf()-1000)
 var newtime = timediff.toTimeString().split(" ")[0];
 document.getElementById('hms').innerHTML=newtime ;
 document.cookie = "remaining="+newtime;
 setTimeout(count,1000);
}
count();
</script>

</html>
```

**PS:** Tried and tested the countdown survives page refresh and accurate even in heavy page throttling >10 seconds!

If you don't want current time but any manual time entered you can always adjust the values to get the desired effect.

Comment: Thanks! 
It is working in Mozilla but the cookie is not working in chrome browser .

Comment: @Namatullah I tested in chrome , cookie is working fine.Make sure cookies are enabled and clear all cookies then try may be .

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to use `document.cookie = newtime`. So every time when you assign newtime to element on the same time newtime should also be assigned to cookie so it may not be lost.

Answer (score 1):

Simple:

Let's assume you need 2 clocks, each with different duration time (if you need more than 2 clocks, or only one, just extrapolate the explanation).

1. Set running and stopped clock styles:

```
       .runningClock, stoppedClock
          {width:75px;
           color:white;           
           font-weight:bold;
           border:3px double white
          }
    
       .runningClock { background:#1ABB9C;  /* use your favorite green/turquoise */ }
       .stoppedClock { background:red; }
```

2. Create each clock in HTML with an ID (I'm using DIV, but it can be a TD, a SPAN or other block object) [ignore extra spaces below, typed here to make code visible]:

- < div id=clock1>< /div>
- < div id=clock2>< /div>

3. within your JS block, build these 2 functions:

```
    function Secs2Clock( numSecs ) { // converts # of seconds to a digital clock format )
        return ( parseInt( numSecs /3600 ).toString().padStart(2,"0") + ':' +
                 (parseInt( (numSecs /60) )%60).toString().padStart(2,"0") + ':' +
                 parseInt( numSecs %60 ).toString().padStart(2,"0") );
    }
    
    function runClock( oneClock, hours, minutes ) {
      var secs=hours*minutes*60;
              
      oneClock.className="runningClock"; // sets it to paint green, running
              
      var runningClock=setInterval( function() { //starts clock refreshing by second
         oneClock.innerHTML = Secs2Clock( secs );
    
         if ( secs>0 ) secs--  // single instruction if true, feel free to add curled brackets for readability
            else {
                oneClock.innerHTML="00:00:00";
                oneClock.className="stoppedClock";
                clearInterval( runningClock );
            }
    
        }, 1000     
      );
       
    }
```

4. Within your main JS block (or your "BODY onLoad" function or wherever you want the clock[s] to launch), add this line for each clock (in this example, 2 different ones); or else within the onClick action or whatever action (A HREF click, etc) where you want the specific clock(s) to start (in this example, this is part of the main JS code, to launch both clocks with different remaining times)

```
    runClock( clock1, 1, 0 );   // will start as "01:00:00"
    runClock( clock2, 6, 30 );  // will start as "06:30:00"
```