# How to access a cookie in javascript?

Tags: javascript, cookies

I'm working on a project which runs a PHP document on localhost.
The PHP accepts and saves-as-cookie some user input.

Then it's supposed to execute a javascript script which uses the data in the cookie to perform a calculation, and return the calculation to the PHP document.

The first part is fine.
The application prompts user for input and saves it to a cookie as expected. 
I check chrome://settings/cookies and see the cookie in locally stored data, Domain: localhost. 
fine.

In the same directory, I have a file called calculate.js.
I know calculate.js is working, and being executed correctly from the PHP, with dummy data.
But: 
How can I save the value of the cookie to a var in calculate.js?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create and read a value from cookie?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825683/how-do-i-create-and-read-a-value-from-cookie)

Comment: Or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10730362/get-cookie-by-name

Answer (score 2):

get cookie content from javascript ?

Javascript

```
var c = document.cookie
console.log(c)
```

PHP

```
$_COOKIE[$cookie_name]
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm still not getting it. I mean, the cookie is defined in PHP, and the Javascript is supposed to (let's say) console log it.  Is that what you have described?

Comment: Why dont't​ you try it? Yes I suppose it is.

Comment: php - [Set cookie] -> javascript get it?  document.cookie not work?

Comment: maybe you can check this, split and get it by name 
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10730362/get-cookie-by-name