# Set div to opacity 0 on clicking hyperlink

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to hide the `cookies-banner-bloc` div when I click `Close this message`. Where am I going wrong?

**HTML:**

```
<div class="cookies-banner-bloc">
    <div class="cookies-banner-container">
        <p>We use cookies on this website.</p>
        <a class="cookies-close-button no-border">Close this Message</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.hide {
  opacity:0;
}
```

JS:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    if(getCookie("userclosedalert")=="true"){
          $(".cookies-banner-bloc").addClass('hide');
            removeClass = false;
    }
    $(".cookies-close-button").click(function () {
       document.cookie = "userclosedalert=true";

    });

});
```

Demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/28860gqj/

Comment: you can use display none property to hide a div using css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use jQuery cookie to manage cookies.
I find it pretty easy to use.

The documentation about how to use is [here](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie)... Event if this GitHub page is no longer maintained, it is usefull for the documentation. The most recent CDN is [here](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery-cookie).

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

  // A console check on the cookie value.
  console.log( $.cookie("userclosedalert") );

  // if the cookie exist
  if($.cookie("userclosedalert")=="true"){
    $(".cookies-banner-bloc").addClass('hide');
    console.log("cookie found");
  }

  // Set the cookie on click
  $(".cookies-close-button").click(function () {
    $.cookie("userclosedalert","true", {expires: 7, path: "/"}); // Expires isn't mandatory and is in days.
    console.log("cookie setted");
    $(".cookies-banner-bloc").addClass('hide');
  });

});
```

[**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/PKewzp?editors=1111)

Answer (score 2):

You have to add the class after the click event as well:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

   if(getCookie("userclosedalert")=="true"){
      $(".cookies-banner-bloc").addClass('hide');
        removeClass = false;
   }
   $(".cookies-close-button").click(function () {
       document.cookie = "userclosedalert=true";
       $(".cookies-banner-bloc").addClass('hide');
   });

 });
```

So it will work after a reload and after the click event.

Answer (score 1):

You are not checking when you clicking on the button.  Just just move your condition inside of click.

However, why you setting and and remove the cookie? I do not see any usage of it here.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $(".cookies-close-button").click(function () {
       document.cookie = "userclosedalert=true";  
     if(getCookie("userclosedalert")=="true"){
          $(".cookies-banner-bloc").addClass('hide');
            removeClass = false;
    }

    });

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/28860gqj/1/

Answer (score 1):

getCookie is nowhere defined, so you get this error 
`Uncaught ReferenceError: getCookie is not defined`. Maybe you shall use `document.cookie`. You can find how to read cookies over here:

[Reading cookies by name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10730362/get-cookie-by-name)

The rest looks good so far, so after this being fixed, everything should work as intended.