# Countdown timer for hours, minutes, and seconds alert when it hits 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, countdown

**I need a alert when the countdown hits 00:00:00**

```
<p>
<span id="hms">00:00:05</span>
</body>

<script>

    var startTime;
    function getCookie(name) {
      var value = "; " + document.cookie;
      var parts = value.split("; " + name + "=");
      if (parts.length == 2) return parts.pop().split(";").shift();
    } // credits kirlich @http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10730362/get-cookie-by-name

    function count() {
     if(typeof getCookie('remaining')!= 'undefined')
     {
       startTime = getCookie('remaining');
     }
     else if(document.getElementById('hms').innerHTML.trim()!='')
     {
       startTime = document.getElementById('hms').innerHTML;
     }
     else
     {
      var ddddd = new Date(); 
      var hhhhh=ddddd.getHours(); 
      var mmmmm=ddddd.getMinutes();
      var sssss=ddddd.getSeconds();
      startTime = hhhhh+':'+mmmmm+':'+sssss;
      //OR
      startTime  = ddddd.toTimeString().split(" ")[0]

     }

     var pieces = startTime.split(":");
     var time = new Date();
     time.setHours(pieces[0]);
     time.setMinutes(pieces[1]);
     time.setSeconds(pieces[2]);
     var timediff = new Date(time.valueOf()-1000)
     var newtime = timediff.toTimeString().split(" ")[0];
     document.getElementById('hms').innerHTML=newtime ;
     document.cookie = "remaining="+newtime;
     setTimeout(count,1000);

    }
    count();
</script>

</p
```

Comment: Why are you setting a cookie for a timer?  Is this for multiple webpages?

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<p>
    <span id="hms">00:00:05</span>
</body>

<script>

    var startTime;
    function getCookie(name) {
        var value = "; " + document.cookie;
        var parts = value.split("; " + name + "=");
        if (parts.length == 2)
            return parts.pop().split(";").shift();
    } // credits kirlich @http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10730362/get-cookie-by-name

    function count() {
        var check = $("#hms").text();
        if (check == "00:00:00") {
            myfunction();
        }
        if (typeof getCookie('remaining') != 'undefined')
        {
            startTime = getCookie('remaining');
        } else if (document.getElementById('hms').innerHTML.trim() != '')
        {
            startTime = document.getElementById('hms').innerHTML;
        } else
        {
            var ddddd = new Date("00:00:05");
            var hhhhh = ddddd.getHours();
            var mmmmm = ddddd.getMinutes();
            var sssss = ddddd.getSeconds();
            startTime = hhhhh + ':' + mmmmm + ':' + sssss;
            //OR
            startTime = ddddd.toTimeString().split(" ")[0]

        }

        var pieces = startTime.split(":");
        var time = new Date();
        time.setHours(pieces[0]);
        time.setMinutes(pieces[1]);
        time.setSeconds(pieces[2]);
        var timediff = new Date(time.valueOf() - 1000)
        var newtime = timediff.toTimeString().split(" ")[0];
        document.getElementById('hms').innerHTML = newtime;
        document.cookie = "remaining=" + newtime;
        setTimeout(count, 1000);

    }
    count();

    function myfunction() {
        alert("Time Up");
    }

</script>

</p
```

Use this code.