# Wordpress Cookie hidden field

Tags: wordpress, cookies, field, hidden

In Wordpress, I try to write o cookie into a hidden field. I have a cookie:

```
   if(isset($_GET['ecselis']))
     {
     $cookie_name = "ecselis";
     $cookie_value = $_GET['ecselis'];
     setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30),   "/");
     $_SESSION["ecselis"] = $cookie_value;
     }

   else if(isset($_COOKIE['ecselis'])) {
      $_SESSION["ecselis"] = $_COOKIE['ecselis'];
     }

   else
     {

     }
```

This working fine. But I dont realy know how should I write it into a hidden field

```
<input id="ecselis_field" name="ecselis_field" type="hidden" value="" />
```

I tried

```
<input id="ecselis_field" name="ecselis_field" type="hidden" value="$.cookie('ecselis')" />
```

but it doesn't work at all.

Comment: `$.cookie` is js library. so without loading library you can't use it. also, this will not work, even if you loaded library: `value="$.cookie('ecselis')"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some solution for you, if you want to use `js/jquery` ( function for getting `cookie` `getCookie()` used from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15724300/8053001) ):

```
function getCookie(name) {
    var value = "; " + document.cookie;
    var parts = value.split("; " + name + "=");
    if (parts.length == 2) return parts.pop().split(";").shift();
}

jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('#ecselis_field').val(getCookie('ecselis'));
})
```

Add this code into some `.js` file of your theme/child theme or create your own one.

*Tested and works.*