# How to fetch cookie value

Tags: javascript, jquery

On page the cookies abc has value

```
{"origin":"DEL","destination":"AMD","fromDate":"17 Jul 2018","toDate":"23 Jul 2018","multiCity":[],"promo":"","market":"","currencyCode":"INR","adults":1,"children":0,"infants":0,"journeyType":"roundTrip"}
```

I want to fetch journeyType value, how should I get the value ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get cookie by name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10730362/get-cookie-by-name)

Comment: this can be easily researched

Comment: Run that string through `JSON.parse`, then access the property as you would any other object

Comment: Hi and welcome to stack overflow. Please read this page on how to ask a question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this:

```js
var cookie_str='{"origin":"DEL","destination":"AMD","fromDate":"17 Jul 2018","toDate":"23 Jul 2018","multiCity":[],"promo":"","market":"","currencyCode":"INR","adults":1,"children":0,"infants":0,"journeyType":"roundTrip"}';
var json_str=JSON.parse(cookie_str);
alert(json_str.journeyType);
```