# how to capture part of data from cookie in javascript

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have a cookie on login to a webpage. HEre are the details of the cookie

```
"{"XXVCode":"T937848","PName":"Garneriere","PAddress":"Dublin 8, southgate","Participation":false,"Coding":true}"
```

i need to capture XXVCode in a variable how could I do this in javascript on this webpage?

Comment: This question might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/q/10730362/7919626

Answer (score 0, accepted):

convert to object, and then access key

```
const cookie = "{"XXVCode":"T937848","PName":"Garneriere","PAddress":"Dublin 8, southgate","Participation":false,"Coding":true}"

const cookieJSON = JSON.parse(cookie)

const XXVCode = cookieJSON['XXVCode']
```

Answer (score 1):

### Method 1:

You can use `getCookie()` function:

```
// Code collected from w3schools.com

function getCookie(cname) {
  var name = cname + "=";
  var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
  var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
  for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
      c = c.substring(1);
    }
    if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
      return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
  }
  return "";
}
```

---

Then you can call:

```
getCookie('XXVCode');
```

### Method 2:

Note: your cookie string wrapped with `double quote`, it should be wrapped with `single quote`. 
Because `double quote` inside `double quote` will show `syntax error`.

```
var cookie = '{"XXVCode":"T937848","PName":"Garneriere","PAddress":"Dublin 8, southgate","Participation":false,"Coding":true}';

var cookieArray = JSON.parse(cookie)

const XXVCode = cookieArray['XXVCode'];
```