# How to get the a sting in javascipt?

Tags: javascript

Please how can i get a username in a text ... 
i'm using cookies on javascript and i tried that but didn't work

```
function getCookie(cname) {
   var name = cname + "=";
   var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
   var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
   for(var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
      var c = ca[i];
      while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
         c = c.substring(1);
         if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
           return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
         }
      }
 return "";
}
var user=getCookie("username");
alert(user);
```

I used that to set the cookie :

```
function setCookie(cname,cvalue) {
  document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue;
}
```

Please how can i acheive that ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get cookie by name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10730362/get-cookie-by-name)

Comment: Could you edit the title so that it makes sense?

Comment: Where did you find that code?

Comment: Your code is correct but you have some syntax error. You need to close the while loop before you start the if statement. 
while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
         c = c.substring(1); }

Comment: Close the while loop after line 8 of your getCookie function. See [tryout here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_cookie_username)

Comment: Thank you @iamcastelli