# How to read value from Response Cookies?

Tags: javascript, cookies, httpcookie

I'm making a POST call to the Back End, the Back End return me the cookie and inside the Network tab, I click on the request and see the status code is 200 OK and in the cookies subtab(inside the Network tab) I see that the Response Cookies has a value with the same domain, how can I read the value of the cookie('PROV') ??

[image: t]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10730362/get-cookie-by-name

Answer (score 0):

You can use cookies-js from npm. I don't know what kind of application do you have, but this module is pretty straightforward, I think that you can use Cookies.get('PROV')

Read more here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookies-js