# How to get cookie in vue.js without dependency?

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, cookies

I set a cookie with `laravel` and now I want to get that in `vue.js`?
and I don't want to use or install any dependency!
How to do that?

It would be highly appreciated if anyone can advise me!

Answer (score 0):

`document.cookie` will give you string of your cookies, then you can parse string and get necessary cookie https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie.

Comment: can I get a specific cookie with a name in this case?

Comment: Yes https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10730362/get-cookie-by-name.