# Reading cookie from Wasm

Tags: go, webassembly

I am attempting to read a cookie from Wasm but have not found any examples so I guessed, but I guessed wrong.

```
c := js.Global().Get("Cookie").Get("cookiename")
fmt.Println(c)
```

This gives me an error:

```
panic: syscall/js: call of Value.Get on undefined
```

Given that I have not found any documentation regarding reading cookies from Wasm.
Is this even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three issues here:

- **the field is on document**, not body
- **the field name is `cookie`**, not `Cookie`
- **the cookie object is a string**, you need to parse it to find the cookie by name.

To get the cookie string, use the following:

```
cookies := js.Global().Get("document").Get("cookie").String()
```

You will then need to process the string to iterate through the cookies and extract the one with the desired name. See [Get cookie by name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10730362/get-cookie-by-name)

As always with wasm, figure out the javascript code first then convert it to wasm.