# How to create a function to split the following string?

Tags: javascript

I have this string

```
"G_ENABLED_IDPS=app; COOKIE_EINF=someCookie; _ga=someGA;
_hjid=someHJID; _gcl_au=someglcau; COOKIE_EINF_SESS=somecookie1; _gid=somegid; _hjIncludedInPageviewSample=2; _hjTLDTest=3; _hjAbsoluteSessionInProgress=0; _hjIncludedInSessionSample=1; _gat_UA-124355-12=5"
```

And i need some sort of function to `split` this string given an argument , for example given that my string is `text`

`text.split(";")` , will split it into an array separating it by `";"`

But i need a function like this

`returnText(text , property)`  that would work like

```
returnText(text, "_gcl_au") --> returns "someglcau"
```

Comment: Also have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10730362/get-cookie-by-name). Just replace `document.cookie` in the answers to them with `text` for your case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could actually use a regex replacement approach here, for a one-liner option:

```js
function returnText(text, property) {
    var term = text.replace(new RegExp("^.*\\b" + property + "=([^;]+)\\b.*$", "gm"), "$1");
    return term;
}

var input = "G_ENABLED_IDPS=app; COOKIE_EINF=someCookie;_ga=someGA;_hjid=someHJID; _gcl_au=someglcau; COOKIE_EINF_SESS=somecookie1; _gid=somegid; _hjIncludedInPageviewSample=2; _hjTLDTest=3; _hjAbsoluteSessionInProgress=0; _hjIncludedInSessionSample=1; _gat_UA-124355-12=5";
console.log(returnText(input, "_gcl_au"));
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use split, just as you tried:

```js
function returnText(text , property){
    entries = text.split('; ');
    const newEntries = [];
    entries.forEach(item => {
       let vals = item.split('=');
       newEntries[vals[0]] = vals[1]
    });
    return newEntries[property];
}
    
const text = "G_ENABLED_IDPS=app; COOKIE_EINF=someCookie; _ga=someGA;_hjid=someHJID; _gcl_au=someglcau; COOKIE_EINF_SESS=somecookie1; _gid=somegid; _hjIncludedInPageviewSample=2; _hjTLDTest=3; _hjAbsoluteSessionInProgress=0; _hjIncludedInSessionSample=1; _gat_UA-124355-12=5";
console.log(returnText(text,'_gcl_au'));
```