# How to store my actions in cookies through JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, cookies

I currently have a checkbox. I want to implement a method as described below~

When the user clicks on the checkbox and it turns into a red background state, this action can be stored in a cookie using javascript. When the web page is refreshed, the red background state is still Exist, how can I write it to achieve it?

```css
label input {
  display: none;
}
label i {
  display: block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border: 1px solid;
  background: red;
}
label input:checked ~ i {
  display: block;
  background-image: url("https://img.magiclen.org/albums/webpage-icon-font/shut-003.png");
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<label>
  <input type="checkbox">
  <i></i>
</label>
```

[example](https://codepen.io/eqoffdzc-the-lessful/pen/WNjLMgY?editors=1100)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set cookies with Javascript Browser DOM:

```
document.cookie = "username=John Doe; expires=Thu, 18 Dec 2013 12:00:00 UTC";
```

This example was taken from w3schools^^
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

From here, you can make a cookie to be like `document.cookie = "background_state = 1; expires=..."`

And then in your code, you simple do something like:

```
function getCookie(name) {
  const value = `; ${document.cookie}`;
  const parts = value.split(`; ${name}=`);
  if (parts.length === 2) return parts.pop().split(';').shift();
}
```

Credit: [Get cookie by name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10730362/get-cookie-by-name)

And from here you do something along the lines of: (at the start of your code)

```
if(getCookie(background_state) //<-- this is referring to the value (if it's 1 its true, if 0 it's false) ){DOM.edit.css.here... };
```

Comment: Sorry~ I am a beginner in javascript, and I still don’t know how to write after reading your question. Is that the way to write it?

https://codepen.io/eqoffdzc-the-lessful/pen/WNjLMgY?editors=1010