# Javascript cookie.match

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have a cookie that I am trying to match it works fine on the online tool but not in the Chrome console using the `[\w+]`. Any help would be great.

```
cookie Name customerid value =2488475
```

In Chrome console, I am trying `document.cookie.match('customerid=document.cookie.match('customerid=([\w+])*');` but it is returning null

Comment: The argument to `match()` should be a RegExp, not a string.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide the output of `console.log(document.cookie)`. I'm not sure what that code block is, but it doesn't look like that.

Comment: Regular expressions are in `//`, not `''`.

Answer (score 1):

As ***Barmar*** said when using **Regular expressions** match method take **//**, not **''**.

follow pattern `string.match(regexp)`, So change **single quotes** with **slash**

```js
document.cookie.match('customerid=[\w+]');
//                    ^                ^
```

***Note:*** The match() method returns the matches in an array and null if no match is found.

To get a value from cookie with regex [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21125098/14529779):

```js
window.getCookie = function(name) {
  var match = document.cookie.match(new RegExp('(^| )' + name + '=([^;]+)'));
  if (match) return match[2];
}
```

In your case call the function `getCookie('customerid')`

Comment: thanks so it would be `document.cookie.match(/customerid=[\w+])`;

Comment: See the update, and tell me if it worked, if not try to `console.log(document.cookie)`?