# Use this JavaScript to load cookie into variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, cookies

I am working from this thread:

[What is the shortest function for reading a cookie by name in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5639346/shortest-function-for-reading-a-cookie-in-javascript)

Which shows that a cookie can be read in JavaScript using the following code:

```
function read_cookie(key)
{
    var result;
    return (result = new RegExp('(?:^|; )' + encodeURIComponent(key) + '=([^;]*)').exec(document.cookie)) ? (result[1]) : null;
}
```

I have a cookie which is set called "country" and its value is two letters, for example "AZ". I am wondering how one goes about reading the value of the cookie and putting it into a variable called cookie_country for example. This regexp is a little above me and I dont know where to start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This...

```
var cookie_country = read_cookie('country');
```

... should be enough for this case. ) The point of this function (as many others) is that it provides you just a tool for extracting a value from `document.cookie` string by some string key (`'country'`, in your case): you don't need to know how exactly this tool works unless it breaks. )

...But anyway, perhaps it would be interesting to know this as well. ) `document.cookie` is actually a string containing a semicolon-separated list of cookies (its key and its value). Here's more to [read about it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.cookie) (MDN).

The regex basically catches the part of this string that matches the given string either at the beginning of the line or at the end of some `;`, then goes on until, again, either the string ends of another semicolon appears.

For example, if `key` parameter is equal to `country`, the regex will look like this:

```
/(?:^|; )country=([^;]*)/
```

... and it will capture the *value* that is stored in `document.cookie` associated with `country` string.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you'll have to read the cookie line-by-line.

```
var rows = document.cookie.split(;);
for (i=0;i<rows.length;i++)
{
    var firstrow = rows[i].substr(0,rows[i].indexOf("="));
}
```

While creating you could put the variables to be between identifiers, something like AZ
The regex should look like this: '##[AZ]{2}##'

Ofcourse, I could be completely wrong :)

Hope this helps.

Comment: While you gave an answer of how to read a cookie, the questioner asked how to read a cookie using the given function. So this answer is incorrect.

Comment: I noticed that too late, sorry.
Maybe I was confused with the fact that questioner was using a regex to find values in his cookie :s