# Read cookies returns undefined

Tags: javascript

Here is my situation.
I have a dropdown to select country on home.

If there is no cookie I set cookie default to "US", Then user open a link in new tab and goes to checkout page, I filter other countries and show only that selected country on dropdown select, everything is fine but when on first tab it changes country to DE on second tab Cookie is DE but the country is still US.

There are two options,

```
<select id="country">
    <option>Select Country</option>
    <option value="US">Select Country</option>
</select>
```

What I want to do is

```
function readCookie(k){return(document.cookie.match('(^|; )'+k+'=([^;]*)')||0)[2]}
```

or any other function to read cookies like some described here [What is the shortest function for reading a cookie by name in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5639346/shortest-function-for-reading-a-cookie-in-javascript)

```
document.getElementById('country').onchange = function () { 
    this.options.length = 0;
    this.options[1] = new Option(readCookie('country'),readCookie('country'));
    this.options[1].setAttribute("selected","selected");
}
```

They return undefined but cookie is there when I inspect with profile. Basically, I just want to renew option based on cookie

when I do

```
document.getElementById('country').onchange = function () { 

    alert(readCookie('country'); //returns undefined
}
```

Comment: I cant read any cookie, thats strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched to localstorage instead.

Answer (score 0):

did you check the path when creating a cookie ? make sure the path is /, i sometimes forget and create 2 cookies or cannot remove the old one.

Comment: Yeap, it is 
country=United+States; expires=Sat, 17 Nov 2012 12:52:53 GMT; path=/; domain=.local.dev; HttpOnly