# Google translate get current language

Tags: javascript, google-translate

After finding zero of anything to help me online....

I am using the current function for a multi language site:

```
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
  new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en', includedLanguages: 'en,es',     layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE}, 'google_translate_element');
}
```

However I have no idea how to get the current language once a user changes it.
I'm not sure if this is even possible. Basically I want to update to Spanish images if 
Spanish is chosen over English. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: it has options for pageLanguage, includedLanguages, and what's the option for the language of the translate button itself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your not gonna believe it:

```
window.setInterval(function(){
     var lang = $(".goog-te-menu-value span:first").text();
     alert(lang);
},5000);
```

I just had to dig to find the container in Firebug and grab the value from the first
span element. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: This won't work because lang will depend on the browser's language settings.

Comment: That element `.goog-te-menu-value span:first` seems to no longer exist

Answer (score 5):

The currently selected language is stored in a cookie named `googtrans`.

Here's a simple example of grabbing the value from the cookie (based on cookie code from here: [What is the shortest function for reading a cookie by name in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5639346/shortest-function-for-reading-a-cookie-in-javascript)):

```
function readCookie(name) {
    var c = document.cookie.split('; '),
    cookies = {}, i, C;

    for (i = c.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        C = c[i].split('=');
        cookies[C[0]] = C[1];
     }

     return cookies[name];
}
console.log(readCookie('googtrans')); //eg. 'en/no' for Norwegian, '/en/hr' for Croatian, etc.
```

Answer (score 2):

Calling `google.translate.TranslateElement().c` gives the code for the current language. For example, "fr" for french, "en" for english, "de" for german.

Inspecting the `google.translate` global object is generally informative. It's a little hard b/c Google's obviously compiled the code such that things like `TranslateElement.c` don't have human readable names, but with a little effort you can make sense of some of the parameters.

Comment: Google has since updated the parameters, so `google.translate.TranslateElement().c` no longer works

Comment: `google.translate.TranslateElement().e` now works for me

Comment: `google.translate.TranslateElement().e` only tells me the initial language, not the current language, once selected

Comment: Fair enough. `.e` was what I needed, but using `.a.sd` in combination would seem to help most people.

Comment: google.translate.TranslateElement().a.cd works for me

Answer (score 2):

Calling `google.translate.TranslateElement().a.sd` gives the identifier of the current language.

> Examples:
>   **"fr"** for French, **"en"** for English, **"de"** for German, **"it"** for Italian

---

Calling `google.translate.TranslateElement().a` is an object of other current parameters, like the Google Analytics tracking code.

Check it out in the console to see what is there. [How do I access the console?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers)

Inspecting the `google.translate` global object is generally informative. It is a little hard because Google is constantly updating the code, making changes to the parameter allocations, and has obviously compiled the code in such a way that things like `google.translate.TranslateElement()` does not have human readable names; with a little effort though, you can make sense of some of the parameters.

Comment: `google.translate.TranslateElement().e` now works for me

Comment: @timpeterson `google.translate.TranslateElement().e` only tells me the initial language, not the current language, once selected

Comment: Fair enough. `.e` was what I needed, but using `.a.sd` in combination would seem to help most people.

Comment: I had to use `google.translate.TranslateElement().c` on my site.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to get the language from the URL.

```
    function getUrlVars() {
    var vars = {};
    var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m,key,value) {
        vars[key] = value;
    });
    return vars;
}
```

Then

```
var selected_lang = getUrlVars()['lang'];
```

Comment: I am receiving `undefined` on the variable. I don't think translate adds anything to the URL, correct?

Answer (score 0):

I am using google translate module in my joomla site. My requirement was that we have one language button at the top. Default the site will be in English. So the button to display on top will be Spanish. When user clicks on the button the page translates to Spanish and the button changes to English and vice versa. This works fine as long you don't refresh the page. 
Now say the translated page is in Spanish and the button at the top is English. Now when you refresh the page the button changes back to Spanish (javascript hide show function, default is Spanish). As I was enable to trace the current language, the language button at the top were not according to the language selected. After to much digging I found this script which helped me resolve my problem. I hope it helps someone else too.

```
<script>
 //to get currently selected language
window.setInterval(function(){
     lang = $("select.goog-te-combo option:selected").text();
    alert(lang);
},5000);
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck in the same problem. After spending a day,i got a hack to read selected language from google translate widget.You can read from html tag as we select,the lang attribute gets updated , You can simply :
`document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].lang`