# How to implement google translation to my application

Tags: javascript, cordova, google-translator-toolkit

I am creating a phone application for my website using cordova. I want to translate my website between Arabic and English.I implement it using google translator API in a java script.This is the code that I used

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function googleTranslateElementInit() {
      new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: '', includedLanguages: 'ar,en'}, 'google_translate_element');
    }
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```

This code works well for my index.html page(home page).But the problem is translation only take place on my index.html page.When I redirect to any other pages from home page,I still remains in English.How can I translate entire pages in my application

Comment: Are you sure that you are calling this script in every pages ? Try adding alert into the function and check when you change the page alert is display or not.

Comment: I added alert  to all pages where this script is used.The alert boxes are also shown in all pages.But language remains english. I need to select language separate for each page to change language.

Comment: You need to set your last selected lang into localStorage and call it on page change or tell the script that which language was selected last. Otherwise it will consider new page to set default language on first load.

Comment: How can I find last selected language from script

Comment: <div class="new_sub_cate_panel_single_div" id="google_translate_element" ></div>
This is the div to display dropdown box and the java script is given in my question

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27488298/3840093) answer of stackoverflow you will get the language name which you have selected first time it will display `undefined`

Comment: Now I get the selected language identifier (eg:ar for arabic) in all pages.Now I need to convert page to that selected language.How can I convert it using language identifier

Answer (score 0):

Set any default language first time for your `pageLanguage` for e.g., `pageLanguage: 'en'`

This function will return you selected language which you can set into localStorage and get it in every page you required

```
function readCookie(name) {
    var c = document.cookie.split('; '),
    cookies = {}, i, C;

    for (i = c.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        C = c[i].split('=');
        cookies[C[0]] = C[1];
     }

     return cookies[name];
     localStorage.setItem("selLanguage",cookies[name])
}
console.log(readCookie('googtrans'));
```

Which you can set with the page load script like

```
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
    var selLang = localStorage.getItem("selLanguage");
    if(selLang !== null && selLang == "ar")
    {
        new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'ar', includedLanguages: 'ar,en'}, 'google_translate_element');
    }
    else
    {
        new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en', includedLanguages: 'ar,en'}, 'google_translate_element');
    }
}
```

Comment: pageLanguage: 'ar' does'nt make any change in my page.but var selLang sets the correct value.