# getting current translated language in any browser

Tags: javascript, browser, translation, google-translate

Is there any way to find the current language of the page.
I want that when 1st page load the browser should show the current language in console.And when I change the language the browser should show the current changed language.
I already tried these methods, but none of these work:

[Google translate get current language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13480879/google-translate-get-current-language)

This always shows en (English language)

```
console.log("Current Language : ", window.navigator.language);
```