# how can I retrieve a cookie that is sent by a WebService

Tags: javascript, html, web-services

There is a webService in a server that my HTML code POSTs a form to it and receives an answer from the webService. but when the webService is called, it sends a cookie with name "ASP.NET_SessionId" (it's value is something like "bmbggmfm2rsi0rvspq5eiqrv"), can I retrieve this cookies value in my HTML code ?

Comment: It seems to me you just need to read cookies in javascript. If so then can you read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5639346/shortest-function-for-reading-a-cookie-in-javascript ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you right, you `POST` some data to a domain different to your page's origin, and want to read a cookie sent from that domain. This is not possible due to security restrictions.

Depending from your needs, there could be a workaround. For example, if you need some kind of session identifier, and this information is considered as legitimate to read, then great chances are that the webservice provides a special method to read the info.

Comment: yes, that's exactly my problem, so I can't have access to the cookies of another domain ? even with document.cookie ?

Comment: No, because the `document` in your page is originated at your site, not the webserice's one. So `document.cookie` contains cookie of your site.