# How to use cookies in HTML website

Tags: php, html, cookies

I have 2 files: first website.html and the second is php.php

In php I have a function that gets cookie from website.html

How can I print the content that was insert in the form below that form without riderecting to php.php

*how can I use data that is stored in the cookie in the HTML website using only php and html

Comment: you can read the cookie by javascript see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5639346/shortest-function-for-reading-a-cookie-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Given some reasonable assumptions: You can't.

HTML is not a programming language and has no way to access cookies or add them to the DOM.

The sensible thing to do is to use PHP. This is most easily achieved by using a `.php` file instead of a `.html` file (although you can configure your server to parse `.html` for PHP directives).

You could also [use JavaScript](/questions/5639346/shortest-function-for-reading-a-cookie-in-javascript) (so long as you didn't set the cookie to be `http_only`, which is usually a sensible thing to do).

Comment: So what you're suggesting is to change  my index.html and all my other html files to .php?

Comment: Yes. Most websites using PHP use it for all their pages.

Answer (score -1):

You can read the **cookie** form **javascript** in html page.

**Read Cookie by Name (JS)**

```
function readCookie(name) {
    name += '=';
    for (var ca = document.cookie.split(/;\s*/), i = ca.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        if (!ca[i].indexOf(name))
            return ca[i].replace(name, '');
}
```

**Read Cookie by Name (Jquery)**

```
(function(){
    var cookies;

    function readCookie(name,c,C,i){
        if(cookies){ return cookies[name]; }

        c = document.cookie.split('; ');
        cookies = {};

        for(i=c.length-1; i>=0; i--){
           C = c[i].split('=');
           cookies[C[0]] = C[1];
        }

        return cookies[name];
    }

    window.readCookie = readCookie; // or expose it however you want
})();
```

**Reference :**

[What is the shortest function for reading a cookie by name in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5639346/shortest-function-for-reading-a-cookie-in-javascript)