# Cookies created with Jquery via radio buttons not transferring

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies

Pretty simple. I have 3 radio buttons, I want people to choose one radio button, click the button to save the selection, and then go to the next page and use the cookie.

Currently have a text input box, and 3 radio buttons. The text input is working, the radio is not.

The idea i had going forward was whichever radio you choose, they're all the same name, they just have a different value set to them. Therefor the value assigned to them is saved as the cookie, and retrieved on the next page. Not working.

Sorry forgot JSfiddle -
http://jsfiddle.net/3kfz7jdf/3/

html -

```
 <form action="javascript:void(0)">
    <input type="text" name="cookie" id="cookie" value="">
   <div id="pics">



   </div>
   <div id="radio">
   <input type="radio" name="char" id="char1" value="1">
   <input type="radio" name="char" id="char2" value="2">
   <input type="radio" name="char" id="char3" value="3">
   </div>
 <input type="button" name="Fight" id="saveCookie" value="Fight" onclick="window.location.href='Battle.html'">
 </form>
```

JS -

```
$(function(){
    // attach event listener to save cookie button
    $('#saveCookie').click(function(){
        // set cookie expiration to 1 year from today
        var expDate = new Date();
        expDate.setFullYear(expDate.getFullYear() + 1);
        // create cookie string
        var cookieStr = $('#cookie').val() + ";expires=" + expDate.toGMTString();
        // create cookie
        var cookieChar = $('#choice').val() + ";expires=" + expDate.toGMTString();
        document.cookie = cookieStr;
        document.choice = cookieChar;
    });

});
```

I dont know if you need the retrieval page, but ill post that as well.

js-

```
$(function(){
        // display cookie 
        $('#cookieDisplay').html(document.cookie);
        $('#cookieDisplay').html(document.choice);
    });
```

Thanks ahead of time.

Answer (score 0):

In the code `JQuery.onclick` is scheduled to run after `window.location.href='Battle.html'`.

To solve it, place relocation of browser at the end of cookie manipulations.

**UPDATE:**
I'm really sorry, I missed a major problem in the code:
`document.cookie` stands for Cookies manipulations while `document.choice` is just a defined variable.
While Browser uses Cookies as inter-domain variables, other variables are available in each document page.
I hope it helps.

```
$(function(){
    // attach event listener to save cookie button
    $('#saveCookie').click(function(){
        // set cookie expiration to 1 year from today
        var expDate = new Date();
        expDate.setFullYear(expDate.getFullYear() + 1);
        // create cookie string
        var cookieStr = $('#cookie').val() + ";expires=" + expDate.toGMTString();
        // create cookie
        var cookieChar = $('#choice').val() + ";expires=" + expDate.toGMTString();

        document.cookie = "cookieStr=" + cookieStr;
        document.cookie = "cookieChar=" + cookieChar;
        // now we relocate:
        window.location.href='Battle.html';
    });
});
```

to read the cookies for each parameter see ([What is the shortest function for reading a cookie by name in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5639346/shortest-function-for-reading-a-cookie-in-javascript))

and remove onclick parameter from input#saveCookie

Comment: Well my question is then, why does the text input work, but not the radio button? It's all within the same form and function.  Also when i add window.location to the bottom of my function, nothing is saved.