# how to parse signed cookie in client through javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, express, cookies, jquery-cookie

i set secret key by Express: `res.cookie('name','value', {signed:true});`
and want to parse the signed cookie in client javascript, such as `document.cookie` or `$.cookie()`, but i can't find out where there is any API for that. 
do anyone know about it?

Comment: What's the problem, exactly? Does your cookie not appear in the list from `document.cookie`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5639346/what-is-the-shortest-function-for-reading-a-cookie-by-name-in-javascript

Comment: it appears but it is encrypted. this is what i got by document.cookie.name or $.cookie('name):`s:0.vunrLqeIl9xNAJFmibUmCeWeI3vDS9m/mbnkAZiVubU`.  as you know,  we can parser cookie in server side. such as `req.signedCookies`, but in client side, there is no such API to do that.

Comment: @epascarello  the method you gave is to just read cookie, and i need to parse the signed cookie in javascript client side, provided i know the secret key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a cookie value of `s:0.vunrLqeIl9xNAJFmibUmCeWeI3vDS9m/mbnkAZiV‌​ubU`, its value will be `0`. The prefix `s:` signifies that its a signed cookie, and the suffix `.vunr...ubU` is the actual signature.

So to extract the value, you can use something like this:

```
let value = $.cookie('name').match(/^s:(.*)\..*$/)[1];
```

Or, if you're using a bundler like Webpack or Browserify, you may be able to use the actual module that it used to create and verify signed cookies in Express: [`cookie-signature`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookie-signature).

Comment: thanks a lot. i thought there was off-shelf API  in client to use directly, but it seems still has to use webpack to bundle module into front end.