# How to attach csrf header and value in axios POST request

Tags: django, csrf

I need to send CSRF token when the user sign up with form provided.

However, since the signup/signin will be the first time to interact with django REST API, so I create a dummy GET request when the webpage is loaded to retrieve the CSRF token from django.

The token is retrieved and stored in cookie.

[image]

However, I still get `Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.)` from django.

This is my axios POST request.

```
import axios from 'axios'
axios.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'vcubes'
axios.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken'

let req = {
    url: 'http://localhost:9000/vcubes/signup/',
    method : 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
    },
    data: data
}
```

NOTE:

When I add `withCredentials: true` into headers in axios POST, the browser send OPTIONS request instead of POST.

Comment: Now there is a new property: `withXSRFToken`. You need to set it `true` to send the XSRF token. https://github.com/axios/axios/pull/6046

Answer (score 2):

```js
  let csrftoken = Vue.$cookies.get('vcubes')

  return axios.post('', data, {
    headers: {
      'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken
    }
  }).then(response => {
    return response.data
  })
```

This is pretty similar to Shane's answer, but show's how to get the csrf token in Vue. If your problem is getting the cookie, then [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25490531/5407229) SO answer should help you.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I use in django:

```
result = { "insert your key values here" }
data = JSON.stringify(result)
axios.post("{% url 'error_checking' %}", data, {headers: {'X-CSRFToken': '{{ csrf_token }}',}})
```