# AngularJS XSRF strategy does not honour cookie paths

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, spring, cookies

I have three spring boot applications running on the same server with different paths. All three of them expose API endpoints and one of them also serve web resources such as `HTML`, `JavaScript` and `CSS`.

**Application 1:**

1. Serves UI files
2. Serves API endpoints

**Application 2**

3. Serves API Endpoints

**Application 3**

3. Serves API Endpoints

So far we only enabled CSRF validation for application 1. Which worked well with `org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CookieCsrfTokenRepository`. We send `XSRF-TOKEN` as cookie and angularJs sends back `X-XSRF-TOKEN` in header in each request.

Now we are planning to introduce `XSRF` to other two applications the same way we did for Application 1.

But we are stuck with a problem. AngularJs sends the XSRF-TOKEN from application 1 and uses the same token for all three applications while each application has its own TOKEN cookies per (application path).

This causes `CSRF` validation to fail for other two services.

Here are the configurations that I use.

```
Spring-boot version     : 1.5.3
Angular version         : 1.3.18

  <beans:bean id="csrfTokenRepository" class="org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CookieCsrfTokenRepository">
    <beans:property name="cookieHttpOnly" value="false" />
  </beans:bean>
```

The Error that I get

```
{
  "timestamp": 1509437659613,
  "status": 403,
  "error": "Forbidden",
  "message": "Invalid CSRF Token '2fa60cb2-803f-4b2b-a1d6-7e10e56ca649' was found on the request parameter '_csrf' or header 'X-XSRF-TOKEN'.",
  "path": "/application2/posturl/path"
}
```

Here the token `2fa60cb2-803f-4b2b-a1d6-7e10e56ca649` is from application1 with cookie path /application1.

**My observations so far:**

1. I checked and made sure all three applications are setting cookies
   to be `httpOnly=false`.
2. I can see that all three applications have
   their own `XSRF-TOKEN` cookies in the chrome developer console with
   their own paths.
3. I did not write a single line at the angular end to
   change its default behaviour.
4. All three applications are running as WAR files on the same IP and Port.

> What I suspect here is that Angular is not honouring the path
>   attribute of the cookies and it goes with the first cookie with a name
>   `XSRF-TOKEN`.

Is there a way to go around this issue?

Comment: Kindly let me know if you need further details on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the issue resolved by changing the `csrfTokenRepository` definition on all three applications along with an interceptor in `AngularJs` to read those `cookies` based on request `URLs` with all the cookies being set to same `Path`.

```
<beans:bean id="csrfTokenRepository" 
    class="org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CookieCsrfTokenRepository">
    <beans:property name="cookieHttpOnly" value="false" />
    <beans:property name="cookiePath" value="/" />
    <beans:property name="cookieName" value="APP-1-XSRF-TOKEN" />
    <beans:property name="headerName" value="APP-1-X-XSRF-TOKEN" />
</beans:bean>
```

Note that the `cookieName` and `headerName` are different for each applications. (Note that the `headerName` doesn't have to different in each of those applications. But I prefer it this way.)

The `AngularJs` interceptor will look something like this.

```
app.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function ($q) {
        return {
            'request': function (config) {
                var readCookie = function (k, r) {
                    return (r = RegExp('(^|; )' + encodeURIComponent(k) + '=([^;]*)').exec(document.cookie)) ? r[2] : null; //CafePasta from https://stackoverflow.com/a/5639455/2557818
                };
                if (config.url.indexOf("/app1") > 0) {
                    config.headers['APP-1-X-XSRF-TOKEN'] = readCookie("APP-1-XSRF-TOKEN", document.cookie);
                } else if (config.url.indexOf("/app2") > 0) {
                    config.headers['APP-2-X-XSRF-TOKEN'] = readCookie("APP-2-XSRF-TOKEN", document.cookie);
                } else if (config.url.indexOf("/app3") > 0) {
                    config.headers['APP-3-X-XSRF-TOKEN'] = readCookie("APP-3-XSRF-TOKEN", document.cookie);
                }
                return config || $q.when(config);
            }
        };
    });
}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the default behavior of Angularjs and Spring
On Spring Security, you should change the xrsft cookie name (One different for each of the 3 applications).

On Angular, you can add an interceptor on each request that dynamically sets the correct cookie value in the header (retrieving it by `$cookies.get(key)`);

Comment: Is there a way i can do this without using different xsrf cookie names...?

Comment: A cookie is a single key/value pair.
If you don't want to change server-side cookie names. You can always create client-side cookies by adding an interceptor on all responses.

Comment: There are attributes like `httpOnly`, `secure` and `path` for a cookie that i know of... You can see the same when you open cookies section of Application tab in chrome dev tools