# How can I use JavaScript (AJAX/jQuery) to tell if a PHP $_SESSION cookie exists?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am working on my `PHP/MySQL` server (website really just a PHP server), and I want to switch from `PHP` echoing to `JavaScript` writing something. I want this because the following reasons.

**1: JavaScript is easier on my page, and**

**2: because for some reason PHP echoing breaks my navigation bar but JavaScript don't. Could I do something like this but tweak it to tell whether it DOES or DOESN'T exist?**

**THIS IS MY CODE:**

```
<script>
document.cookie = "username='<?php echo $_SESSION['username'] ?>';";
var u = document.cookie;
document.getElementById("username").innerHTML = u();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> for some reason PHP echoing breaks my navigation bar but JavaScript don't

This sounds like an issue we could probably fix if we had a sufficient amount of code and an example of the HTML source at runtime.

Regardless - and this is probably a lot less straightforward than echoing a variable - you could set a cookie in PHP and retrieve it in JavaScript with no inline PHP tags needed. Some example code:

PHP (read about [setcookie](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php)):

```
setcookie("username", $_SESSION['username']);
```

JavaScript (function from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25490531/4573410)):

```
function getCookieValue(a) {
    var b = document.cookie.match('(^|;)\\s*' + a + '\\s*=\\s*([^;]+)');
    return b ? b.pop() : '';
}

var u = getCookieValue("username");
```

Comment: can i set the "Grizzly" part in setcookie to <?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?> ?

Comment: @Grizzly I've updated my answer to show how you'd do that. Again, that code would be among your other PHP (so it wouldn't need an inline PHP tag).

Comment: it's not putting any text down?