# Create an array of id's in cookie JS

Tags: javascript, cookies

I want to update the cookie from my WP page with the post id's that the user is visiting. But my problem is that each time the value from the array is deleted and the array contains always just on id, and the next id's are just overwited.

```
 let post_id = my_script_vars.postID; // this is a variable with some id's
 let arr = [] // i create an array

 function setCookie(name,value,days) {
  var expires = "";
  if (days) {
      var date = new Date();
      date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days*24*60*60*1000));
      expires = "; expires=" + date.toUTCString();
  }
  document.cookie = name + "=" + (value || "")  + expires + "; path=/";

}

index = arr.indexOf(post_id);
if (index == -1) { // if the id is not in the array the push it
  arr.push(post_id);
  } else { // if it is in array then keep all of them
    arr.splice(index, 1);
  }
setCookie("id_film",JSON.stringify(arr),30);
```

[image]

and i want my array to keep all the id's and not just one.

Comment: Get the cookie to load visited post IDs into `arr`, then check if you need to push current ID.

Comment: it's working, but the array will always have just one ID(the current one), but i need all of them

Comment: What he meant is that when you initialize the "arr" variable, it should contain the former IDs. If you initialize the "arr" variable each time and push the new ID you will only get the new ID in the array.

Comment: aaa, and how can i initialize the arr variable with the former IDs?=)

Comment: i dont really know how to get the visited post IDs into array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow these steps:

- Don't create your `arr` variable until you need it
- Add a [function to read cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5639346/what-is-the-shortest-function-for-reading-a-cookie-by-name-in-javascript#answer-40786282) and return contents as JSON
- On page load, read the cookie, update your array, then save new contents

Final code should see like this:

```
 let post_id = my_script_vars.postID; // this is a variable with some id's

 function setCookie(name,value,days) {
  var expires = "";
  if (days) {
      var date = new Date();
      date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days*24*60*60*1000));
      expires = "; expires=" + date.toUTCString();
  }
  document.cookie = name + "=" + (value || "")  + expires + "; path=/";

}
// Function to read cookie and return as JSON
function getCookie(name) {
    let a = `; ${document.cookie}`.match(`;\\s*${name}=([^;]+)`);
    return a ? JSON.parse(a[1]) : [];
}

// Be sure to execute after DOM is loaded
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    // Get saved IDs
    let arr = getCookie('id_film');
    index = arr.indexOf(post_id);
    if (index == -1) {
        // if the id is not in the array the push it
        arr.push(post_id);
    }
    setCookie("id_film",JSON.stringify(arr),30);
});
```

Comment: thank u so much, finally i understand how this works, and its not so hard after all, thankssss=)))