# how to convert {obj:"{objects}"} into array with json object inside it

Tags: javascript, json

I had % in my cookie and I found following code for it and got the data below after implying that code

```
var cookies = (document.cookie);
var output = {};
cookies.split(/\s*;\s*/).forEach(function (pair) {
    pair = pair.split(/\s*=\s*/);
    var name = decodeURIComponent(pair[0]);
    var value = decodeURIComponent(pair.splice(1).join('='));
    output[name] = value;
});
console.log(output);
```

The data console is down below;

```
{"objName":"[{"key":1,"key2":"value 123","key3":"value123"},{"key":1,"key2":"value 123","key3":"value123"}]"}
```

I have the data as shown above, What I want is to objName into array and remove "" from in front of [] array barckets

```
objName=[{"key":1,"key2":"value 123","key3":"value123"},{"key":1,"key2":"value 123","key3":"value123"}]
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45015/safely-turning-a-json-string-into-an-object

Comment: just call `JSON.parse` again on the property

Comment: Where do you get that shown data from (what you show is not valid JSON). If you generate that data you should fix the generation first.

Comment: I have change my question, JSON.parse(abc) is showing error : [obj obj] is not valid json.

Comment: @vee I dont think that is the solution as my data contains json string inside the array not object.

Comment: There is only one cookie that is extracted.

Comment: @DanielBeck, I tried the console.log(output) but the value is same as mentioned in the question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the shortest function for reading a cookie by name in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5639346/what-is-the-shortest-function-for-reading-a-cookie-by-name-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you are trying to get cookie values, you can try this code and handle the returned array as you need. You can try this solution and let me know if it works.

```
var cookies = document.cookie.split(';').reduce(
    (cookies, cookie) => {
      const [name, val] = cookie.split('=').map(c => c.trim());
      cookies[name] = val;
      return cookies;
    }, {});
console.log(cookies);
```

Comment: This doesnot work as required as it returned cookie value as it is in this way cookievalue =cookievalue%cookievaue%. This might need to be json parse or stringify to get desired result

Comment: The second one , didn't try the first one though. @DreamBold

Comment: You can try the first one and let me know. @sumitkhatrii So I can update the answer accordingly. :)