# read cookies in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

On textbox onchange property i have called one javascript function
In that I have written this,

```
function testbox1()
{

var strline1side1 = document.frmartwork.side1textbox1.value;
document.cookie="lineside1="+strline1side1.replace(" "," ")+";path=/;";

}
```

I want to assign this "lineside1" cookie value when page is reload

```
window.onload=function()
{

document.frmartwork.side1textbox1.value = "here i want that cookie "


}
```

How can i do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Read Cookies using Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2657906/read-cookies-using-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

You should use jquery cookie [plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie)

```
function testbox1()
{

var strline1side1 = document.frmartwork.side1textbox1.value;
$.cookie('lineside1',strline1side1.replace(" "," "));

}

window.onload=function()
{

document.frmartwork.side1textbox1.value = $.cookie('lineside1')


}
```

Comment: $('#side1textbox1').val($.cookies('lineside1'));
I used this but its not working

Comment: document.frmartwork.side1textbox1.value = document.cookie['lineside1'];


But its showing me "undefine"

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery - use [jQuery.cookies](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) plugin. It's quiet simple to use.

```
$.cookies('cookiename') // get value
$.cookies('cookiename', value) // set value

function testbox1()
{
    $.cookies('lineside1', $('#side1textbox1').val());
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#side1textbox1').val($.cookies('lineside1'));
});
```

Also, if you start using jQuery - use it :)